# Gráfica Excel Subclasificación

Tags: excel, ordenamiento, gráficas, excel-2013, excel-2010

tengo esta información de la cual estoy generando una gráfica, pero quisiera agregar una subclasificación.

**Actualmente tengo la tabla y gráfica de la siguiente manera:**
[image: Gráfica Actual]
**Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de agregar una subclasificación de forma que quede algo como esto, tomando los datos de la columna A:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias por su apoyo....

Comment: Prueba a usar un gráfico dinámico en vez de gráficos normales

Answer (score 0):

Selecciona las celdas de A1 hasta C7 y luego le das insertar al gráfico de barras que necesitas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo ten en cuenta que los registros en el campo "Estado", deben ser mencionados una vez y estar escritos donde va a empezar a agruparse los registros del campo "Nombre" para que esto funcione.